# order values in alphabetical order in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a pandas dataframe called feature. I want to order the values of "feature" in an alphabetical order. For example, in the below table, how can I get all the values under age in the order age, color, gender?

```
ID  Feature
1001    color,age,gender
1002    age,gender,color
1003    age,color,gender
1004    color,age,gender
1005    age,color,gender
1006    color,age,gender
1007    age,color,gender
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way, but, honestly, i don't like it:

```
In [24]: df.Feature = df.Feature.str.split(',', expand=True).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sort(x)).str.cat(sep=','), axis=1)

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
     ID           Feature
0  1001  age,color,gender
1  1002  age,color,gender
2  1003  age,color,gender
3  1004  age,color,gender
4  1005  age,color,gender
5  1006  age,color,gender
6  1007  age,color,gender
```